# Android: Resize an JPEG from SD Card without losing quality

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, jpeg

Usually I find everything I need using the search function of StackO. But now (success less) I’m really trying hard to resize a JPEG from SD Card without getting bad quality. As follows, you can see that the original Image is clean and perfectly readable. After resizing I will always get a blurred result.

Original: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5h4cdkz29vkapw/signature.jpg?dl=0

Scaled:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/tobijbu5hisf9rz/signature_small.jpg?dl=0

At the following code passage you can see everything I tried without success (I hope I am wrong, but I think this passage includes all the really useable answers from StackO.) :

```
 public void saveSignature(View view) throws IOException {
    image = signature.getImage();
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File final_location = new File(sd, "signature.jpg");

    try {
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            final_location.createNewFile();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(final_location);

            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.close();

            //Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,(int)(image.getWidth()*0.4),(int)(image.getHeight()*0.4), false);
            //Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 300,75, false);

            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // "works but Color ist gray from sampling" bmOptions.inSampleSize = 5;

            final_location = new File(sd, "signature_small.jpg");
            final_location.createNewFile();
            os = new FileOutputStream(final_location);

            Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sd +"/signature.jpg",bmOptions);
            Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 349, 86, true); //also tyed false (without any Change)

            out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It would be nice to get some answers or links to samples for Android (4.0 and higher).

Thanks for your help in advance,
Tough!!

Comment: `Resize an JPEG from SD Card without losing quality` JPEG, by definition is a **lossy** file format. Meaning that **each time** you re-save it, you will **loose quality**. Therefore, the question has no answer.

Comment: So, you think I have to live with this Problem?

Comment: No, if you remove the `without losing quality` spec. Or simply switch to using **PNG**s.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect to scale down an image without losing quality?

Anyway, to scale down correctly you need to blur the image first, preferably with a [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) kernel, but a box blur will probably be fine. The kernel size should match the scale you wish to scale to. After that you can scale down the image with any interpolation technique. [Lanzcos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling), [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) or even [nearest neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) will be good enough. An alternative approach is to use some kind of area sampling, where each pixel in the target image is a mean of an area of pixels in the source image. Another alternative is to use some kind of [supersampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling).

If you don't do any of these, you'll end up with crappy images. But even if you do it correctly, you will lose quality. Because the scaled down image will have less information than the original.